# Add column to database from model to controller in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

In the Yii MVC,

I've added a column to my database in my model using:

`$success = Yii::app()->ft_website_prod->createCommand()->addColumn('ft_website.users', 'columnname', 'varchar(64)');`

I now need to know how to get this to execute using the controller. I'm new to Yii so even though i've read as much of the Docs as possible, I still can't figure this out.

Comment: What error does it gives you ??

Answer (score 0):

New column could be added to the table as shown

```
Yii::app()->db->schema->addColumn( 'table_name', 'column_name', 'column type ' );
```

And droping column as shown

```
Yii::app()->db->schema->dropColumn( 'tables_name', 'column_name' );
```